# Dimax sub20 GPIO get/set device configuration

Tags: java, dll, jna

Using JNA.  I'm trying to communicate with sub20 device using `sub20.dll`.
Using `sub_gpio_config()` function, I get or set GPIO configuration but I'm confused about error code which return by function.

The data type of error code is `int`, but how handle in Jna Programming.

**in c/ other lang.,**

```
int gpio_error_code = sub_gpio_config(Device_Handle* handle,int set,int* get, int mask)
// this is very simple.
```

**in jna coding(inside interface)...**

```
sub20api INSTANCE = (sub20api) Native.loadLibrary("sub20", sub20api.class);

 public int sub_gpio_config(DeviceHandle handle,int set,Pointer get, int mask);
```

but during implementation of method., what i do inside body..??
-> i try to implement enum of error code., i'm not sure its work or not...

plz help me..
thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Use `IntByReference` for your `get` parameter.  If your native code uses `enum` for error codes, you need to figure out the integer value of each one and define those values on the Java side.

Comment: thanks., it is helpful...